# Microphone plug-in power battery module

Tags: microphone, lavalier, xlr, battery

I am looking for something like this (on ebay or aliexpress)

[image]

but couldn't find it so far. (something similar is presented here: https://vimeo.com/66941739)

It's a 1.5v battery module to power a lavalier mic (Samson LM10).

Otherwise, will a Rode vxlr+ work to power my Samson LM10? (I will be using an audio interface).

The thing is that vxlr+ delivers 3V and as far as I understood the Samson LM10 requires 1.5V. I really don't know what are the risks on plugin in a lavalier 1.5V mic to 3V.

Thanks in advance for helping on this.

Comment: It's a phantom powered device. What makes you think it will run off 1.5v? It's supplied with adaptors to 3 major connector types - http://www.samsontech.com/samson/products/microphones/lavalier-microphones/lm10/ Why not use one of those & the phantom supply from your interface?

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, in the pdf http://www.samsontech.com/site_media/support/manuals/LM10_OM_5L_v2.pdf it says operating voltage 1.5-12V and I red that several lavaliers mics are 1.5V so I made a 1.5v operating voltage assumption for this mic. I don't see any information about being phantom powered, which is 48v, so I am not sure about powering this mic directly to phantom. But if the operating voltage is 1.5 - 12V range then the Rode VXLR+ at 3V should work, right? Or what you are saying is that the adaptors provided already are converting voltage properly to connect this mic to a 48V phantom plug ?